# What does the question mark mean in Keras Reinforcement Learning and how can I replicate it?

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I'm currently working on a reinforcement learning model, and have come across an issue while trying to create a DQN to work within my custom environment.

While instantiating the DQN agent with this line:

```
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy,
                   nb_actions=(None,actions), nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
```

Note that actions = 3 (integer).

I get the error code:

```
raise ValueError(f'Model output "{model.output}" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case {self.nb_actions}.')
ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_2/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 3
```

After digging into the DQN files, I noticed that the error is arising by the fact that

(?,3) != (None,3)

From my understanding the question mark is simply a placeholder to represent an unknown amount of data points. So why does it have a problem with None not being equal to it and how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is this DQNAgent class? It is not part of Keras and you need to clearly specify it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the keras-rl library.

The `nb_actions` parameter should be an integer that specifies the number of total possible actions that you can perform in your environment.

Taking the [Taxi-v2 environment from OpenAI Gym](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Taxi-v2/) as an example, we can obtain the number of total possible actions via:

```
import gym
ENV_NAME = "Taxi-v2"
env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)
nb_actions = env.action_space.n
```

If your `actions` variable is the number of actions, you can try:

```
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
```